# How can I send email to recipients listed on another node connected using entity reference?

Tags: rules, entities

I have a content type `Job Listing` which defines characteristics of a job (position, full-time status, salary, etc).

I've also created an Entityform Type of `Job Application` which includes an Entity Reference field to a `Job Listing` node.

When Job Applications are submitted, I'd like the system, using rules or another contrib module, to look at the referenced job listing, grab any email addresses listed there and send them a notification that a new application has been submitted for their job posting.

I've installed Entityforms Notifications, Entity Rules, and their dependencies, but I'm swimming in configuration and can't figure this out.

Surely someone has done this before. Any help would be appreciated.